# Where to add a function in React classes - before render() vs in render() vs outside of the class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    #1 - when to add code on the class?

class WrappedHorizontalLoginForm extends React.Component {

    #2 - when to add code on the class?

    handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const user = event.target.elements.user.value;
        console.log(user)
    };

    render() {

    # 3 - when to add code in the render?

        return (<div> 

                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                        </Form.Group>
</div>
```

Can someone kindly point out cases on when to add a function in the class vs when to add code within the render method vs when to add it outside the class?
Are their generic guidelines to follow in terms of functionality or specific code?
`handleFormSubmit` in the code above can be used as an example to explain.

Comment: It's kind of a broad question. There are specific guidelines for the [`render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) function as it is a lifecycle method. However, asking for what else your component class should look like would be opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

Any code in the render method will run when the component rerenders due to a change in state or props etc. So say you have a component which shows a table of data from a database and it has some state of which cells are selected etc. You would not want to run the database get query when you select a cell as it is not changing. So for that you would have the database request in something like `componentWillMount` rather than in the render method.

Generally code in the render method is for things such as defining temporary variables or if and else clauses. You want to write most code in the designated react class methods.

Also writing thread blocking code in the render method will reduce the speed of your site.

Comment: for the code in the question as an example, would it be the same defining `handleFormSubmit ` inside the class or outside the class ?

Comment: @JosephAdam if `handleFormSubmit` uses or changes the state via `this` then it should the function should be a member of the class/component

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put code just before the render method execution - you probably want to use the component life-cycle methods instead.

if you wants to keep working with Classes so you can use the **componentWillMount** that will execute just before the component is mounted into the dom.

if you want to work with **Functional Components** so as part of React 16.8 there is a new feature that called React Hooks.

You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: for the code in the question as an example, what LifeCycle would you add `handleFormSubmit ` ?

Comment: it doesn't look like you need to use any life cycle here - you should attach the handler to the onSubmit event on the form tag - can you add the entire render function?